# load another page into update panel without using iFrame tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iframe

I have one static page that have one menu and one updatepanel tag. by selecting menu items i want to load another page into update panel now i use iFrame tag for do this and on menu items click i have change iFrame's src property but it have some major problems
I want to load another page into current page in asp.net ajaxly without using IFrame tag like blogger , getclicky and other popular sites.

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap your page content into user control rather whole new asp.net page itself. Then by selecting menu items you hide and display right user controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx#Y700